# deal with arrays of Kotlin with Long variables

Tags: kotlin

I have a question about Kotlin.
I tried two versions of Kotlin, 1.0.0 and 1.2.6.
Using Kotlin, we can initialize an array and access to its element like this.

```
val n: Int = 10
val arr = Array(n, { it } )
val i: Int = 0
println(arr[i])
```

However, I got an error with this code.

```
val n: Long = 10
val arr = Array(n, { it } )
val i: Long = 0
println(arr[i])
```

It seems that it is an only way to cast Long to Int in order to compile this code.

```
val n: Long = 10
val arr = Array(n.toInt(), { it } )
val i: Long = 0
println(arr[i.toInt()])
```

However, it seems too redundant to me, but I couldn't find any solutions. So my question is

1. Is there any way to initialize arrays and access elements with a Long
   variable?
2. Does Kotlin have any reasons that Long variable should not be accepted here?

Comment: Array indexing is done using `Int`s, it won't work with `Long`s.

Comment: JVM array indices are always `int`s. You will always have to cast it to an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin comes with `longArrayOf(1, 2, 3)` which will create an array for you which contains `Long`s.

Note that what you are trying to do with `println(arr[i])` is getting a `Long` value out of `arr`, but the **indexing** of arrays is done with `Int`s. It will never work with `Long`s:

```
/** 
 * Returns the array element at the given [index]. 
 * This method can be called using the index operator.
 */
public operator fun get(index: Int): Long
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize an array of longs of the given length, you can use the same top-level `Array` function:

```
val n = 10 // n is Int
val arrayOfLongs = Array(n) { it.toLong() } // Array of 10 longs
```

Here the number `n` is `Int` and the initializer function converts the integer index `it` of an element being initialized to `Long`, therefore we get an array of longs as the result.

Or you can use another similar function to create a specialized `LongArray`:

```
val longArray = LongArray(n) { it.toLong() } // LongArray of 10 longs
```

Both arrays store longs, but the latter does it more compactly.